# Access object in object for the next date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know this has been asked before but I can't seem to find the answer, how to access data in data event, I want to show data for the next date in the collection `JadwalBooking`.

**Schema:**

```
"keterangan" : "keterangan di rubah",
"dataevent" : {
   "time_start" : 60,
   "time_end" : 660,
   "_id" : ObjectId("5b3da607acddef1c24317dd0"),
   "name" : "event 1",
   "description" : "lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum",
"date" : ISODate("2018-11-25T00:00:00.000Z")
 }
```

**Query:**

```
const data = await JadwalBooking.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            dataevent: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    date: {
                        $gte: new Date(new moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")),
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:
        {
            _id: 1,
            dataevent: 1,
            keterangan: 1,
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { date: 1 }
    }
]);
```

Comment: `$elemMatch` for arrays. Use dot notation to access the sub fields. In your case `{
        $match: {
            "dataevent.date":{
                        $gte: new Date(new moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
                    }
                }
            }`

Comment: is you dataevent an `array`? in the given schema, it looks like it is an `object`, and not  `array of objects`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use dot notation for query and sort in datevent date:

```
 const data = await JadwalBooking.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
        "dataevent.date": {
            $gte: new Date(new moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
        }
    }
  },
  {
    $project:
    {
        _id: 1,
        dataevent: 1,
        keterangan: 1,
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { "dataevent.date": 1 }
  }
 ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use `$elemMatch` for your case, `$elemMatch` is used, when you want to query a specific `Object` from an `array of Objects`, and return only matched Object from the array.

In your case a simple query with "." notation will work.

**Try this:**

```
const data = await JadwalBooking.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            dataevent.date: {
                $gte: new Date(new moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:
        {
            _id: 1,
            dataevent: 1,
            keterangan: 1,
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { date: 1 }
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As not mentioned specifically to the `aggregation`,

```
db.collection
  .find({"dataevent.date" : {$gt : new Date(new moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"))}})
  .sort({"dataevent.date": 1})
```

**One more thing is:**

Based on your schema you really don't need to use `$project` too. As you are retrieving whole data.

> ***Note:-*** `$elemMatch` is used for Arrays, you need to use `dot notation`.

```
const data = await JadwalBooking.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "dataevent.date": {
        $gte: new Date(new moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { date: 1 }
  }
]);
```

Comment: `$project` may not be needed but recommended. As per the documentation, `$project` can take advanteage of aggregation pipeline optimization and documents will be of a smaller size, meaning gain in performane for both client and server: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#projection-optimization